# Replacing CSV cell values using ForEach-Object -PipelineVariable

Tags: powershell, csv

I have large CSV files in this format (simplified, many more columns)

```
|Id|Category|Url|
```

the fields separated with semi-colons. Assuming I have a file with the following data

```
id;category;categoryUrl
1;Xyz;http://1.com
2;Xyz;http://1.com
3;Xyz2;http://2.com
4;Xyz;http://2.com
```

I'd like the result to be that of

```
id;category;categoryUrl
1;1;2
1;1;2
3;3;4
4;1;4
```

```
key;value
1;Xyz
2;http://1.com
3;Xyz2
4;http://2.com
```

The gist of the matter the category data can a be longer string, so does the URL too and in fact there are tens of columns *some of which* I would like to preprocess like this and leave the rest as-is. As part of some preprocessing, I would like to replace the repeating values with surrogate IDs and write the resulting CSV file to the disk (not replacing the original one). Then I'd like to also write the generated surrogate IDs together with the real values to another CSV file.

I have currently the following script, but for some reason it doesn't output anything and I'm rather dumbfounded as to why not. Can someone help?

```
$categoryTable = @{}
$categoryId = 0
Import-Csv "data.csv" -Delimiter ';' | ForEach-Object -PipelineVariable row {
  if ($row.category) {
    if (!$categoryTable.ContainsKey($row.category)) {
      $categoryId += 1
      $categoryTable.Add($row.category, $categoryId)
    }
    $category = $categoryTable.Get_Item($row.category)
    $row.category = $category
  }

  if ($row.categoryUrl) {
    if (!$categoryTable.ContainsKey($row.categoryUrl)) {
      $categoryId += 1
      $categoryTable.Add($row.categoryUrl, $categoryId)
    }
    $categoryUrl = $categoryTable.Get_Item($row.categoryUrl)
    $row.categoryUrl = $categoryUrl
  }
} | Export-Csv -Path data_categorized.csv -Force -NoTypeInformation

([PSCustomObject]$categoryTable) | Export-Csv -Path categoryIds.csv -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

**<edit:**

*Ansgar's* solution, with a cue from *wOxxOm* was more than complete! For the benefit of the other people, I'll include the script in its entirety

```
$categoryTable = @{}
Import-Csv "data.csv" -Delimiter ';' -PipelineVariable row | ForEach-Object {
if($row.category) {
    if(-not $categoryTable.ContainsKey($row.category)) {
        $categoryTable[$row.category] = $categoryTable.Count + 1
    }
    $row.category = $categoryTable[$row.category]
}

if($row.categoryUrl) {
    if(-not $categoryTable.ContainsKey($row.categoryUrl)) {
        $categoryTable[$row.categoryUrl] = $categoryTable.Count + 1
    }
    $row.categoryUrl = $categoryTable[$row.categoryUrl]
}

$row
} | Export-Csv -Path categoryIds.csv -Delimiter ';' -Force -NoTypeInformation

$categoryTable.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object @{n='key';e={$_.Value}}, @    {n='value';e={$_.Key}} | Export-Csv -Path categoryIds.csv -Delimiter ';' -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I don't think I follow how your example compares to the original. It is possible you are looking to transpose but I am not sure either.

Comment: Hmm, the purpose is just to replace long, often repeating strings with shorter surrogates. If the files are hundreds of megabytes and much of them is repeating information, it quickly adds up and hinders the actual downstream processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get an empty file `data_categorized.csv` because you don't output the rows in the `ForEach-Object` loop, and as [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701690/replacing-csv-cell-values-using-foreach-object-pipelinevariable/39702533?noredirect=1#comment66703524_39702533) pointed out in the comments, the variable defined by [`-PipelineVariable`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884.aspx) is for use in downstream cmdlets. Replace `$row` with the [current object variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) `$_`, and add a `$_` at the end of the loop:

```
... | ForEach-Object {
  ...
  $_
} | Export-Csv ...
```

The file `categoryIds.csv` should contain data, though, but not in the format you expect. Casting the hashtable to a custom object would give you this output

```
1,2,3,4
Xyz,http://1.com,Xyz2,http://2.com
```

instead of this output:

```
key,value
1,Xyz
2,http://1.com
3,Xyz2
4,http://2.com
```

To get the latter you need something like this:

```
$categoryTable.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object Key, Value | Export-Csv ...
```

Also, you define the category IDs as the values of the hashtable and the categories and category URLs as the keys, so you'd actually get this output:

```
key,value
Xyz,1
http://1.com,2
Xyz2,3
http://2.com,4
```

If you want the IDs in the `key` column you need to re-label the fields, e.g. with [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
$categoryTable.GetEnumerator() |
  Select-Object @{n='key';e={$_.Value}}, @{n='value';e={$_.Key}} |
  Export-Csv ...
```

As a side note: you're over-complicating the hashtable handling. Something like this should suffice:

```
if (-not $categoryTable.ContainsKey($row.category)) {
  $categoryTable[$_.category] = $categoryTable.Count+1
}
$_.category = $categoryTable[$_.category]
```

Note also that your exports don't specify a custom delimiter, so the output files will be comma-separated instead of being separated with semicolons. Add `-Delimiter ';'` to the `Export-Csv` statements to fix that.

Comment: PS4+ `-PipelineVariable` affects only the [next cmdlet in pipe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884.aspx) so here it should moved to `Import-Csv`.

Comment: An indeed, otherwise the `$row` variable will be null! I'll add the new script and accept Ansgar's answer, it anticipated my next rookie problems too! :D

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the correction. For the OP's problem I'd probably just switch to `$_`, though.